# my results are only written on the first row

Tags: python, csv

I am beginner in python. When my program is working I am getting data of a while loop, which is saved in a csv file. However, the results are overwritten on the first row. So, the file only has the last one output.

```
     csv_out = open('results.csv', 'w')
        mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=';')
        rows = zip(k, l, m, h, c, n, r)
        mywriter.writerows(rows)
        num+=1
        csv_out.close()
```

Example of prints:

```
['100 ', '1', 'a', '2', '0', '223', 'x']

['250', '5', 'b', '1', '0', '10', 'z']
```

results.csv only has the row  250;5;b;1;0;10;z. Thanks.

Comment: Indentation isn't correct and you don't have a print statement so the script can't give the example output you've shown. Can you clean this up enough to show us code you actually use that fails? if its something simple like an while loop in the wrong place, we can't spot it unless we get the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file every time for writing, which means you're overwriting the contents with each new line.

You either open the file with mode `a` instead of `w` to append to it, or preferably open the file *outside the loop*, then write to it and close it after the loop.

The latter is preferred since opening the file in append mode will probably result in unwanted content if the file exists.

Comment: OP is doing `writerows` and doesn't have a loop.

Comment: @tdelaney they say they are getting results from a while loop and as you can see there is only one result in the call. Clearly this is not the whole code

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Thank you! That was exactly my mistake.

Comment: @Ignacio Then why didn't you show us that code? Please update your question so that the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try Mode 'a' (append) instead of 'w' (write).

Comment: Why? OP is creating a file and doing `writerows`. That's normal. Unless he updates his example code we can't make an assumption like this.

Comment: I interpolated from his problem descripton rather than going into much detail about his code... which he said is not finished, and obviously... ;)  so yes, I dare make that assumption ;)